# The entity or complex type 'Test3Model.ItemCustomer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net

this is my controller

```
public DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IEnumerable<ItemCustomer> model = null;
            model = (from c in db.Customers
                     join i in db.Items on c.CID equals i.CUSTOMERID
                     select new ItemCustomer
                     {
                         newid = i.CUSTOMERID,
                         customername = c.NAME,
                         itemname = i.PNAME
                     });

            return View(model);
        }
```

this my index

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.newid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customername)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemname)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I'm trying to get specific data from different tables based on some requirements, The program is supposed to take some columns of choosing from tables: item,customer
i used database first

Answer (score 0):

Assumed `Test3Model.ItemCustomer` is a mapped entity class in Entity Framework, obviously you cannot use it to project LINQ to Entities query result like this:

```
model = (from c in db.Customers
         join i in db.Items on c.CID equals i.CUSTOMERID
         select new ItemCustomer
         {
             newid = i.CUSTOMERID,
             customername = c.NAME,
             itemname = i.PNAME
         });
```

But you can project it to a viewmodel/DTO class (or anonymous type) like this:

```
// Viewmodel
public class ItemCustomerViewModel
{
    public int newid { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string itemname { get; set; }
}

// DTO query & pass viewmodel to view
IEnumerable<ItemCustomerViewModel> model = (from c in db.Customers
         join i in db.Items on c.CID equals i.CUSTOMERID
         select new ItemCustomerViewModel
         {
             newid = i.CUSTOMERID,
             customername = c.NAME,
             itemname = i.PNAME
         }).ToList();

return View(model);
```